# Dart String Comparator

Tags: dart

What is the best way to compare Strings in Dart?  The String class does not contain an `equals` method.  Is `==` recommended?

For example:

```dart
String rubi = 'good';
String ore = 'good';

rubi == ore;
```

Comment: I realised generated strings would be well compared when put in quotes as variables `'$rubi' == '$ore';`

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Yes, `==` is the way to test if two Strings are equal (contain exclusively the same sequence of characters).  The last line of your code evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 27):

Strings are immutable objects, which means you can create them but you can't change them. You can of course build a new string out of other strings, but once created, the string's contents are fixed.

This is an optimization, as two strings with the same characters in the same order can be the same object.

```dart
String rubi = 'good';
String ore = 'good';

print(rubi == ore); // true, contain the same characters
print(identical(rubi, ore)); // true, are the same object in memory
```

Comment: `===` has been replaced with the built-in function `identical()`.

Answer (score 14):

Unlike *Java*, [Dart](http://dartlang.org) allows to override operators such as `==`. So you can define your own test for this operator to check equality. You can also use [indentical function](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core.html#identical) to check whether two references are to the same object (the equivalent of `==` on objects in *Java*).

For [String](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/String.html)s, it's a little special. Depending on how you instanciate the [String](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/String.html) you can have different results with DartVM :

```dart
main() {
  final s = "test";

  printTests(s, "test");
  // displays '==' => true    'identical' => true

  printTests(s, "$s");
  // displays '==' => true    'identical' => false

  printTests(s, new String.fromCharCodes(s.codeUnits));
  // displays '==' => true    'identical' => false
}

printTests(String s1, String s2) {
  print("'==' => ${s1 == s2}    'identical' => ${identical(s1, s2)}");
}
```

As you can see `identical` returns `true` only for the first case and `==` always `true`. But that's not always true. If you run this code in javascript after a *dart2js* compilation, `identical` and `==` always return `true`.

In most case you want to compare the values of String not their references, so you should use `==`.

Comment: Note that currently printTests(s, "$s");  prints  both true for == and identical because "$s" is interpreted as a constant literal as well.

Answer (score 7):

(For completeness sake, here is another way to compare two strings.)

`String` in Dart implements the `Comparable` interface. You can use `compareTo` to compare strings.

```
String rubi = 'good';
String ore = 'good';

rubi.compareTo(ore) == 0;
```

You need to check for NULL values though.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to compare String. Depending on your need, you should choose an appropriate solution:

1. Using operator **str1 == str2**: The operator returns true if the str1 equals str2. Otherwise, it returns false.
   This operator is useful when you want to determine whether the strings have the same sequence of code units.
2. Using **str1.compareTo(str2)** method: the method returns a negative value (-1) if str1 is ordered before str2, a positive value (1) if str1 is ordered after str2, or zero if str1 and str2 are equivalent.
   This method is useful if you want to sort a collection of strings.